# Remove bad GPS signals inside building

Tags: algorithm, filter, gps

I have a problem I can not solve, when the GPS data logger is inside a building, the units still reads data "with much noise". Thus, when the unit is kept static, it still reads data and the recorded points jump in a mad way. i.e., if I kept the unit for 2 hours on a desk. I will still record points that are distant from each other by e.g. 150 meter.

This is a problem to me as I want to make a program that calculates the total distance that the unit has moved. So, if I kept the unit fixed on the desk for 3 hours, the unit keeps recording many data points that are distant  from each other by e.g. 150 meter. So, my program will read that the unit has moved for 20 KM during this period although it was not moving.

I have tried to filter the obtained data by HDOP, PDOP, VDOP, but it only removed 5% of bad data points. I tried to also filter data by the number of satellites that the gps logger reads, but this also did not identify all bad signals.

I know that there is no solution to prevent this error it is due to the technology itself as GPS is not designed to read inside buildings. My biggest problem is to remove these data points not to be calculated by my program. I know there may be some filters that work.

If you wish, I can attach an excel file having some data which are recorded inside building. My aim is only to make my program know what these points are so that I can remove them from my calculations. Please note that the speed, heading are zeros because I configured the device not to store these parameters, but If you need these data for filtering, I can send you the data.

Comment: how often do you sample data points? If moment is such as the velocity is aver an threshold then than can be used for filtering.

Comment: Does the device have an accelerometer? Otherwise, couldn't you filter out jumps between points that would imply that the device has moved insanely fast?

Comment: Dear Gentlemen ,   my sampling rate is one reading every 5 seconds. for the issue of velocity ,I will try  right now. I have also uploaded a csv file with all data you need and 2 simple photos after plotting these data . Please check the below link   http://www.4shared.com/file/PL6OuWy7/zodo-20110612.html

Comment: Dear Phil ,   No , the device does not contain accelerometer unfortunately.. Do you mean to use Kalman filter  using data from GPS and that from the accelerometer sensor ? .

Comment: I will check the velocity issue and tell you in few minutes the results

Comment: use a sliding window (start with perhaps 30 seconds) to calculate average and discard points that fall too far from that average

Comment: Perhaps you could specify in your excel dataset which points you consider as invalid, so we can test a few tricks and compare the outcome with your expected result

Comment: Please prepend your messages with @usename (@belisarius, for example), for the other party to get notified

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We use data that's logged in cars, and we're not interested in position data that's collected when the phone is charging on somebody's desk. I think our approach will solve most of your problem.

I deal GPS noise as follows:

- To get rid of 90% of the useless noise, the logger stops logging when there's no movement (no measurement with a speed of more than 10km/h), or no signal for more than 3 minutes. That way we don't cut holes when somebody is waiting for a traffic light or at corners; During post-processing we'll remove the trailing noise if there was indeed no movement for a longer period.
- As soon as there's are 3 consecutive measurements with a speed of over 10 km/h, we assume that it's not just noise, and we store everything that we've buffered back until the first measurement with a speed < 2 km/h.  That way, if a car slowly leaves, we still capture it driving away.

At this point we've filtered out 90% of the noise, but we're still left with minor noise when somebody stands still during trips. We deal with that as follows:

- If there's a short period without movement, all of the positions with a low speed are interpolated over a bezier curve between the last movement before standing still, and the first movement after standing still. The position, speed and heading are taken into count. A linear interpolation (or simply removing these measurements) will probably provide usable results with a smaller effort.

There are some extra heuristics to make sure that slow driving in traffic jams is not seen as GPS noise, by measuring both the traveled raw distance, and the distance between the first and the last position in the period.

This was all implemented for an assignment where an accuracy of 99% for distance calculation is required, so a lot more is involved. For example by matching to a map, planning routes to verify the matches, and to fill up gps in the signal in tunnels or when the signal was bad because of reflections, and by checking if the headings, positions and speeds of consecutive measurements match (you can always use any 2 of those to calculate the 3rd one). But this is basically what we do to filter out most of the GPS noise.

If you don't have to calculate stuff in real-time, you've got a great advantage that you can look "into the future", which makes it a lot easier to filter stuff.

Comment: Dear Wouter , Thanks for you support , I really appreciate it so much . Regarding your recommendations , it seems rich logic which I understand . I will try to apply it to my data and feedback you after analysis to inform you results today. But , my first impression is that I am interested in the locations that persons stays at and how long he/she stays at.

Comment: It is answers like this that make me wish I could "favorite" answers.  Thank you!

Comment: Dear Wouter , Thomas , both your solutions were genius and very inspiring  , thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You could find all "rest locations" - a radius in which your logger stays for a given amount of time - and filter out all nearby points.  This would cause you to not track something like a three mile jog on a 400 meter track (because all the points will be close, even though the person is in motion) but so long as all your distance-centric concerns are more mobile then this should work fine.

The other suggestion of filtering on speed is great because lots of time GPS warmup or momentary errors can be 100+ meters per second and if you're tracking cars chances are you don't believe anything over 80 m/s.  Here is some example code, written in the [Haskell programming language](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell), that uses the [GPS package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gps-0.6) I maintain on Hackage:

```
import Data.GPS
import System.Environment
import Data.List
import Control.Monad

main = do
        file <- liftM head getArgs
        xs <- readGPX file
        let rests = restLocations d t xs  -- all points within 100 meters for two minutes
            goodPoints = xs \\ concat rests   -- all points that aren't considered rest locations
            bestPoints = filterByMaxSpeed s goodPoints
            totalDist = map totalDistance [xs, goodPoints, bestPoints]
            lxs = length xs
            lgp = length goodPoints
            lbp = length bestPoints
        putStrLn $ "We filtered out " ++ (show $ lxs - lgp) ++ " points by eliminating\
                   \ all points where the device stayed in " ++ show d ++
                   "meters for " ++ (show t) ++ " or more seconds.\
                   \  We filtered an additional " ++ (show $ lgp - lbp) ++
                   " points by eliminating movements over " ++ show s ++ " meters / second"
        print $ totalDist
  where
  d = 100
  t = 120
  s = 35
```

First we open the file and read all points into the variable named `xs`.  We then find all rest locations (points within 100 meters for 120 or more seconds) and remove said points, resulting in the variable `goodPoints`.  Finally, we remove all points that would require the device to have moved over 35 meters per second (78mph), leaving us with the result of `bestPoints`.

When I run this on some really noisy data I have sitting around I see:

```
 $ ./so ~/Maps/23Apr2011.gpx 

 We filtered out 26601 points by
 eliminating all points where the
 device stayed in 100.0 meters for 120s
 or more seconds.  We filtered an
 additional 6 points by eliminating
 movements over 35.0 meters / second
 [NaN,6724.717043334737,6676.349134626797]
```

The bottom line shows the total distance when considering points `xs`, `goodPoints`, and `bestPoints`.  As you can see, `xs` overflows the `double` while the distances of `goodPoints` and `bestPoints` are more reasonable.

Comment: I have tried filtering data by speed over 1.8 , it has improved results by 40 % , but there is still 60 % .

Comment: First , thanks for the speed issue . Second , I am waiting for your genius solutions gentlemen.

Comment: Dear Thomas ,   Your solution looks very logic , but the problem , how to find stay points within a circle of 50 meter . do you have algorithm to do this or you want to make a loop and check for each point ?

Comment: Hi all , Any progress ? .  Thanks all for your support

Comment: @Wsn Just so you understand how StackOverflow works - the questions are _your_ problem (the askers), it is the asker who is expected to make progress - those of us who volunteer our time to answer are just helping you along.  We generally hope the asker will gain some understanding of the problem and be capable of solving similar issues, if they arise.  That said... yes, I have made progress.  I happen to maintain the `gps` package on Hackage, so I took this as an opportunity to fix the package up a little.  See my edit (I do it in a few minutes) for an example.

Comment: Dear Thomas , Thanks so much for your support . I really appreciate it so much , and forgive me for being so curious to get the answer . I really understand that you waste your valuable time to those who have problems and you share you knowledge/experience. So , thanks again and forgive me. I will check you approach and give you results by today. Thanks again.

Comment: Dear Gentlemen , I still have the problem , can you support me by playing around with gpx file with the faulty data I have. If you kindly have a time to check the file , I will send it to you .  Thanks all.

Comment: WSN: If you can host the file somewhere then feel free to post a link - preferrably by editing your quesiton and commenting on the answer(s) that it's been edited with said information.